# angular can't find a controller when using require.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

so in this example:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    {{name}}
</div>

function myController($scope){
   $scope.name = "Jack Robinson";
}
```

it works. but how do I use it with require.js? Next snippet doesn't work

```
define(function(){
   return function myController($scope){
      $scope.name = "Jack Robinson";
    }
})
```

it says: 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: RequireJS I think is an overkill when you combine it with AngularJS. The requirement for Requirejs is hugely reduced, if not unnecessary with Angular. Just my 2 cents..

Comment: explain that please. How is that require.js and AMD overkill? Does angular has it's own mechanism to asynchronously load javascript files on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a template / starter project with RequireJs and AngularJs

https://github.com/jhiemer/angularjs-requirejs-testacular

Comment: can't.. I'm trying to marry asp.net mvc, require and angular altoghether

Comment: @Agzam : The repo mentioned already provides necessary tools to make Angular and require work together and it seems like you already know how to get require and asp.net mvc to work together. I dont understand why you dont think so? Are you looking for a solution that marries all three? Your question btw doesnt say so...

Comment: Require and Angular are purely JavaScript frameworks. They don't care what runs on the server. Using the template above you can extract the JavaScript portion of the app and still use it with ASP.NET MVC.